# Powershell - File name change Date

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a daily date generated CSV file

Eg: **File_1_20220321.CSV**

How do I use Powershell to change the year to 2015 so the file name would be:

Eg: **File_1_20150321.CSV**

Comment: `Get-Item -Path 'X:\somewhere\File_1_20220321.CSV' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_2022', '_2015'}
`

Comment: @Theo Is there a way that I can make it automated instead of manually renaming the date as each year pass? For eg, when the year is 2023, it will rename the year to 2016.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the renaming of the file with today's date in its name to have a date 7 years ago, you can do the following:

```
$today  = Get-Date
$filter = '*_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv' -f $today
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\somewhere' -Filter $filter -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "_$($today.Year)", "_$($today.AddYears(-7).Year)"} -WhatIf
```

I have added safety switch `-WhatIf` to the Rename-Item cmdlet.
This makes the command only **show in the console** what *would* happen and nothing actually gets renamed. Once you are satisfied the code will rename correctly, remove that `-WhatIf` switch and run again.

---

If the dates in the replacement need to be **valid** (like when today would be the 29th of Februari and changing the year to 7 years ago, you will end up with an invalid date), use this code:

```
$today        = Get-Date
$todayPattern = '{0:yyyyMMdd}'-f $today
$olderPattern = '{0:yyyyMMdd}'-f $today.AddYears(-7)
$filter       = '*_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv' -f $today
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\somewhere' -Filter $filter -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "_$todayPattern", "_$olderPattern"} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you automatically generate the date for the csv-File via

```
Get-Date -uformat "%m%d%Y"
```

which is the most logical way to do it for a clean formatting, you can simply add another parameter:

```
Get-Date -uformat "%m%d%Y" -year "2015"
```

Hence the way to export your log would be:

```
$dateold = Get-Date -uformat "%m%d%Y" -year "2015"    
Export-Csv -Path "C:\yourpath\filename_$dateold.csv" -InputObject $myobject
```